# Scatter plot with same color for values below a threshold

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to generate a scatter plot of coordinates(x,y) where the color is decided by a value ranging between (-3,1.5). How do I plot all the points with value less than -1 with same color without them being omitted from the plot all together. I tried to use `im.set_clim(-1,1.5)` , but it cutoff the values below -1 and didn't plot.

How do I do this?

A follow up question :

Is it possible to have sequential colormap where the values below -1 are all red (no gradient) and above -1 are having a sequential colormap which does not start with a shade of red.

Comment: @JohanC, thanks for the help. Can you please have a look at the follow up question?

Comment: Follow up questions should be new questions or at least you should accept and upvote the correct answer before posting the follow up... @JohanC nice answer and implementation of the `set_under` method!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the answer to first question was given in a comment, so I posted the follow up question by editing the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vmin` and `vmax` indicate which c-value corresponds to the lowest and highest colors of the color map. Default, all values lower than `vmin` get the lowest color (dark purple for the 'viridis' map). You can change this color with `cmap.set_under(...)`. The `extend=`  parameter shows the under color as a triangular arrow in the colorbar.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 15, 50)
y = - np.sin(x) / (x + 1) * 8
num_colors = 10
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis', num_colors)
cmap.set_under('red')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap=cmap, vmin=-1, vmax=1.5)
plt.colorbar(extend='min')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]